# Why does SignalR recommend using finally to propagate errors in streams?

Tags: asp.net-core, signalr

The [SignalR docs on streaming](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/signalr/streaming?view=aspnetcore-5.0) state:

> Wrap logic in a `try` ... `catch` statement. Complete the `Channel` in a `finally` block. If you want to flow an error, capture it inside the `catch` block and write it in the `finally` block.

They then proceed to give an example that goes through these convolutions for no apparent gain. Why is this? What difference does it make whether one captures an exception and completes the channel from the `finally` block versus completing then and there in the `catch` block?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Possibly to centralize the writer completion logic, even if takes just a single invocation - and you may want to insert additional related logic there (such as logging), if needed.

```cs
Exception localException = null;

try
{
    // ...
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    localException = ex;
}
finally
{
    writer.Complete(localException);
}
```

versus:

```cs
var completed = false;

try
{
    // ...
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    writer.Complete(ex);
    completed = true;
}
finally
{
    if (!completed)
    {
        writer.Complete(null);
    }
}
```

Comment: The real reason is because if you call Complete twice on a ChannelWriter it throws, so your second example is bad if there was an exception. You could change the finally to TryComplete, but it looks cleaner to just complete once.

Comment: Good catch, I have edited the second code example so that it now correctly calls Complete(...) just once.

Comment: I think you're right, though it would be nice if the docs were explicit about this. In my case, I use `TryComplete` and also the stream never completes unless the client chooses to, so I think storing the exception may be a little superfluous, but will play around with it all the same. Thanks!